# Set in $\mathbb{R}$ with no open intervals.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a compact set of $\mathbb{R}$, containing no open intervals. Does it follow that the set is totally disconnected?

Comment: Is $X$ a finite set of points?

Comment: It's closed & bounded. Suppose it's infinite....

Comment: Sure, but will it be a collection of isolated points?

Comment: If it's infinite then you can pursue the "How to catch a lion in the desert" strategy to find an accumulation point.

Comment: @user287517 No, it could be the Cantor set, which is compact, totally disconnected, uncountable and has *no* isolated points.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that there were a connected $C\subseteq X$ with at least two elements. In this case we have two points $a, b\in C$, $a<b$. Now by the assumption we have that $(a,b)$ is not a subset of $X$ and therefore there's a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that $c\notin X$ and therefore $c\notin C$. The intervals $(-\infty, c)$ and $(c,+\infty)$ will decompose $C$ which contradicts that it was connected.

I don't see why $X$ have to be compact. Maybe I've made a mistake?

Comment: I think compactness is superfluous in the reals, indeed.